# Codeigniter not calling function in form action

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, model-view-controller, backend

I am submitting a form using codeigniter but it doesnt call the controller function. The form is displayed when a button is clicked using jQuery. Below is the code

```
     $("#leave_btn").click(function(e) {
        $("#event").text('Apply for Leave');
        var_form=' <?php echo form_open("student/apply_leave_validation"); ?>'+
                                '<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>'
        + '<label>'+'Select Warden:'+'</label>'+
 '<select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="leave_warden">'+
    '<option value="99100">XYZ</option>'+
    '<option value="99101">ABC</option>'+
  '</select>'+'<br>'+'<label>'+'<input type="text" class="form-control" name="leave_going_to" placeholder="Going to">'+'<br>'+
 '<label>'+'From date:'+'</label>'+'<input type="date" name="leave_going_date" class="form-control" >'+'<br>'+
 '<label>'+'To date:'+'</label>'+'<input type="date" name="leave_going_till_date" class="form-control" >'+'<br>'+
'<textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" name="leave_message" class="form-control" rows="8"  placeholder="Any other info">'+'</textarea>'+'<br>'+
    '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="" value="Apply">'+
'<?php echo form_close(); ?>';
                $("#notf_display").html(var_form);
                 });
```

My function in the controller `student.php` is given below

```
  public function apply_leave_validation(){
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">'.
        'alert("This function is called");'.
        '</script>';
}
```

But after submitting it does not display `This function is called`

Comment: right click inspect element, inside the DOM inspector, check the form's action attribute, see if its correct

Comment: @Ghost Its good idea it is showing <!--?php echo form_open("student/apply_leave_validation"); ?-->

why it is getting commented automatically ?

Comment: I noticed that you are using bootstrap. Why don't you create a modal with all the form HTML in it? Then you can simply do `<?php $this->load->view("path/to/modals/leave_form_modal.php", FALSE);?>` and on the leave btn, just add `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#leave"`